# How to handle character encodings properly in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to wrap my head around unicode and different character encodings in Python 2.7.

As far as I know:

- `encode('utf-8')`: converts utf-8 text (`<type 'unicode'>`) to bytes (`<type 'str'>`)
- `decode('utf-8')`: converts bytes (`<type 'str'>`) to uft-8 text (`<type 'unicode'>`)

Based on the above, say I wanted to write some code capable of handling input in any encoding (which I certainly should be doing). The way I do this is:

```
raw_input().encode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

(Note that `sys.stdin.encoding` is UTF-8 in my case)

This should give me a bytes representation of the users whatever encoded input. However, what happens is this raises an exception:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

(Note that it says decode error on encoding? What?)

Now let us try:

```
raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

This gives me a `<type 'unicode'>`. This means, that `raw_input()` gives me  a bytes representation (`<type 'str'>`) of the user input. I can confirm this by:

1. `raw_input()` --> I enter the characters 'űáéő' --> I get `<type'str'>`: '\xc5\xb1\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc5\x91'
2. `raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode(sys.stdin.encoding)`
   --> I enter the characters 'űáéő' --> I get `<type 'str'>`: '\xc5\xb1\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc5\x91'

Right now I feel confused. I've always thought encodings were some kind of black magic, because thats what most people told me. But now: If what I get from `raw_input()` is an already byte representation (`<type 'str'>`) of the users unicode input (and thats what I need to be able to work with it, let's say generate it's hash or anything like that) than **what's this huge confusion in most programmers about encodings?**

I mean it doesn't seem that terrible at all. What I get from inputs is bytes, I only need to **make sure I don't mix up inputs from different sources without making sure they are the same encoding.** Developing an application which gets all it's input from the same terminal, **I don't have to do anything special.**

**Are my assumptions correct?** Also, **is this true in other languages?** (Do I always get the user input as bytes?) If it's that easy, **why is that** most **legacy code** and even **new code messes encodings up?** (in any language)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track but you've been mislead that all Unicode problems are resolved in Python 2.x

In Python 2.x stdin (including `raw_input()`) is not automatically decoded. This is in contrast to stdout, where Unicodes are *encoded* on output.

When reading from a stdin source, you must decode it from a byte string to a Unicode.

Obviously, you need to know what encoding to use for decoding. Python uses the user's locale for the output encoding and the same can be manually used for input decoding.

E.g.

```
my_unicode = raw_input().decode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

`locale.getpreferredencoding()` is the best source of encoding, as `sys.stdin.encoding` is set to `None` when Python doesn't have a terminal. I.e. when piping:

```
$ echo € | python -c "import sys ; print sys.stdin.encoding"
None
```

In Python 3, input is decoded to Python3/Unicode strings and output is encoded. This relies on the user having a healthy locale and set to match their terminal emulation.

In other languages:

### Java

Java's String()s are always decoded bytes. Stdin and stdout is automatically decoded/encoded. InputStreams for file and network input are byte streams that require decoding byte-by-byte or by using text wrappers, such as Readers. Readers can use the system encoding or be defined as a property. Java has a system property/command line argument, `-Dfile.encoding` which can override Java's opinion.

### PHP

AFAIK, PHP only byte strings. Many methods assume iso-8995-1/latin. There's a number of MultiByte methods, which understand UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: `input` mean your  example. i got default encoding `utf-8`. so wrong `system setup` and `python setup`. Please read `how to install an os with all enviroment variables`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The above statements in my answer are true on vanilla cPython 2.x on OS X and Linux. You may be getting different results for Python 3 or if you're performing the commands incorrectly. If you want to link to a document to tell me how to setup my machine, please provide the href. Do you have links for AIX and Solaris also, as I have experience on these also?